# Helmet.js / Express Content Security Policy errors with Angular ngCspNonce

Tags: content-security-policy, helmet.js

**Edit:**
FYI, my problem this was probably caused by [PrimeNG](https://primeng.org/), the component framework i was using.
There are [various](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/12855) [CSP](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/14257) related issues with the library.
I ended up not using the nonces, but using SSRI hashes (by compiling the Angular files using the `--subresource-integrity` flag.
Then I calculating the hashes with [ssri](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssri), and passed that to Helmet.

Can anyone help me with a Content Security Policy configuration issue?
I'm setting up a new Angular v17 project, hosted through a ExpressJS backend on Google Cloud AppEngine.

Unfortunately I keep getting errors like:
`Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'nonce-TESTNONCE123abc'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-iKJahwY4ryjjFnDI8Iu0CVhTGbf2E5wqHhIzgODvwh8='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.`
[image: errors]

**The Backend**
I'm using HelmetJS to set the headers, and want to do it with a nonce.
(for debugging I'm always giving the same hardcoded nonce `TESTNONCE123abc`, but I'll generate a proper one for each request)

```
app.use(helmet(
        <HelmetOptions>{
            contentSecurityPolicy: <any>{
                directives: {
                    defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
                    scriptSrc: [
                        "'self'",
                        "'nonce-TESTNONCE123abc'",
                        "'unsafe-inline'"
                    ],
                    styleSrc: [
                        "'self'",
                        "'nonce-TESTNONCE123abc'",
                    ],
                    fontSrc: [
                        "'self'"
                    ],
                }
            }
        }
    )
)
```

In the browser, I see the headers being set succesfully:

```
Content-Security-Policy:
default-src 'self';
script-src 'self' 'nonce-TESTNONCE123abc' 'unsafe-inline';
style-src 'self' 'nonce-TESTNONCE123abc';
font-src 'self';
base-uri 'self';
form-action 'self';
frame-ancestors 'self';
img-src 'self' data:;
object-src 'none';
script-src-attr 'none';
upgrade-insecure-requests
```

Which https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/ thinks is pretty good!
The only 'medium severity finding' is `script-src 'self' can be problematic if you host JSONP, Angular or user uploaded files.`
But otherwise than that, all green checkmarks!

**The frontend**.
The primeng index.html file has this line:
`<app-root ngCspNonce="##CSP_NONCE##">`

when building the frontend, you see that placeholder nonce is used for the inline styles & scripts.
like `<style nonce="##CSP_NONCE##">`  and `<script nonce="##CSP_NONCE##">`

The placeholder `##CSP_NONCE##` then gets replaced with the nonce in my express route, by `TESTNONCE123abc`.
[image: Successfull replacement]

The other relevant piece of configuration might be my angular configuration:

angular.json -> projects.app.architect.build.options:

```
...
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets",
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "src/assets/fonts/",
    "output": "/fonts/"
  }
],
"styles": [
    "src/styles.scss"
]
...
```

and
angular.json -> projects.app.architect.build.configurations.production:

```
...
"optimization": {
  "scripts": true,
  "styles": {
  "minify": true,
  "inlineCritical": true
},
"fonts": true
},
"outputHashing": "all"
...
```

And as far as I can figure out, that should all be fine... but why am I still getting errors then?.

Comment: Helmet maintainer here. Not sure what's going wrong. Is it possible that some inline styles are being set by your Angular app, and those aren't being nonced correctly? In other words, your `<style>` tags are correct, but something else in your app is not.